# IF EXIST(To check row exist in table) condition not working in SQL Procedure(AS400)

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, procedure

I have one table and two different SQL procedures(AS400) to Insert/Update records to that same table. Both the SQL procedures having IF EXISTS condition to handle the data.

```
IF EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD001 = 'test') THEN

Update table....

ELSE

INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('test')...

ENDIF;
```

But still am getting duplicate records in my table with mili seconds difference.

```
Ex.1st record is --> 2017-07-24-04.21.47.485832

   2nd record is --> 2017-07-24-04.21.47.487468
```

These tables could be Inserted/Updated interactively as well as batch. Anyway How come this is possible for duplicate records..?. Please experts give some possibilities where/when/how duplicate records will be inserted.

And also i don't want to fix this with UNIQUE INDEX, PRIMARY KEY etc... 
Sorry I didn't attach any coding with this.

Thanks,
Loganathan.

---

> Adding codes here,,,

---

The table which I mentioned earlier will insert/update from various ways, but we confirmed these records were inserted interactively from a single session using below single procedure.

Original Records in table.

```
 9243548  CUSTYPE 2017-07-10-16.53.09.825860 2017-07-10-16.53.09.825860      
 9243548  ROYALTY 2017-07-10-16.53.09.485832 2017-07-10-16.53.09.485832
 9243548  ROYALTY 2017-07-10-16.53.09.487468 2017-07-10-16.53.09.487468
```

Calling program:

```
if v_res_spec_sts <> '' then                              
 if (v_res_spec_sts <> v_current_res_spec_sts           
  or v_current_res_spec_sts IS NULL) then               
  call SPCASPECSV (p_resvnum, c_Royalty, v_res_spec_sts,
                 p_updateUser, p_updateProgram) ;     
 end if;                                                
end if;
```

Procedure:

```
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CASPECLPF WHERE RSRES# = P_RSRES#  
              AND RSCOND = P_RSCOND) THEN               
  UPDATE CASPECLPF SET                                      
  RSSSTS = COALESCE(P_RSSSTS, RSSSTS)                       
  ,RSSLCM = TODAYMONTH                                       
  ,RSSLCD = TODAYDAY                                         
 ,RSSLCY = TODAYYEAR                                        
 ,RSSLCU = COALESCE(P_RSSLCU, RSSLCU)                       
 ,RSSLCP = COALESCE(P_RSSLCP, RSSLCP)                       
 WHERE RSRES# = P_RSRES# AND RSCOND = P_RSCOND;             
    ELSE                                                        
 INSERT INTO CASPECLPF                                      
 (                                                          
RSRES#                                                     
,RSCOND                                                    
,RSSSTS                                                    
,RSSLCM                                                    
,RSSLCD                                                    
,RSSLCY                                                    
 ,RSSLCU                       
 ,RSSLCP                       
 )                             
 VALUES                        
 (                             
 COALESCE(P_RSRES#, 0)         
 ,COALESCE(P_RSCOND, ' ')      
 ,COALESCE(P_RSSSTS, ' ')      
 ,TODAYMONTH                   
 ,TODAYDAY                     
 ,TODAYYEAR                    
 ,COALESCE(P_RSSLCU, ' ')      
 ,COALESCE(P_RSSLCP, ' ')      
 );                            
  END IF;
```

Comment: Please show exact insert and update statements with the data that is going to be inserted. Where is that duplicating? On update or insert? Are you sure that it is duplicating in ELSE statement?

Comment: I'm certain this could happen if I'm understanding correctly that both a batch and interactive process could be performing the read/insert simultaneously without any locks.  There is documentation for an exclusive table lock at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/db2/rbafzmsth2lockt.htm

Comment: Sorry am too late to reply.. 

I confirmed these two records was inserted interactively from single session. Also Add timestamp and Change timestamp valuse are same for both the records (so no more updates on these records). 

I will provide my code below.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they are not in different sessions i.e. inserting in one session and not doing the commit, then second session would obviously not find the record inserted in 1st session.

Also if that is not the case, please provide the code.

Comment: I have attached the code in question itself. Sure this happens in single session.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not a duplicate.

If you had a primary or unique key defined, the system would have prevented the second process from writing a record at 2017-07-24-04.21.47.487468.

As it is when the second process checked for a record at 2017-07-24-04.21.47.485500, one didn't exist.  But by the time the second process inserted a record the first process had also inserted a record.

Even with a primary key, the existence check and insert are two separate operations.  You'd still have to monitor for a duplicate key on the insert and handle appropriately.

The `MERGE` statement is usually preferred for such "upsert" (`UPDATE or INSERT`) operations.  However, even with a atomic merge, a second process could insert a record between existence check & insert.  You have to use a locking level of *RR (repeatable read) which basically locks the entire table to ensure that no process can add a record between the existence check and the insert.

With processes inserting microseconds apart, locking the entire table is going to hurt.

You really need to define a primary key, or at least a unique one.

Comment: Now i noticed these records only inserted via interactive there is no more two process. In the table ADD_PROGRAM column having the program name which runs interactively.

Comment: @LoganathanLogu, think you need to look again...what you're describing wouldn't happen.  Perhaps there's an older `SPCASPECSV()` out there that you're calling instead of the one you think you are.